# Can `__has_cpp_attribute` be used as a reliable way to check attribute support?

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-platform, preprocessor-directive

I stumbled upon a disappointing behavior with GCC 9 regarding `[[likely]]`/`[[unlikely]]` attributes support and `__has_cpp_attribute`.

GCC 9 have [introduced](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html) an experimental support for `[[likely]]`/`[[unlikely]]` attributes. The attributes are available even if compiled with `/std:c++17`. But if you try to use them in `if` statement as in the [working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4741.pdf) it will fail to compile ([small code example](https://pastebin.com/hc3BH3Tj)).

And in GCC 10 the same code seems to be working well.

The problem here is that it seems like we still don't have a way to check if an attribute can be used in code or not despite having `__has_cpp_attribute` feature in the language. That's because it only [tells](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) whether an attribute is available or not, not whether it's fully implemented or not.

Before discovering this problem I had checks using `__has_cpp_attribute` ([example](https://pastebin.com/rAFYqK4W)) in my code. Right now I'm adding an additional check for the GCC version there (something like `__GNUC__ >= 9 && __GNUC__ < 10`), but it's definitely a crutch.

**Can I check more reliably that an attribute is implemented and ready to use?**

What `__has_cpp_attribute` can be used for?

Maybe I'm missing something?